# How do I dynamically export Class methods as standalone functions in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am rewriting an old NPM module in TypeScript, and I ran into an interesting problem.

The module, in its current state, looks like this -

**1.1** *my-module.js*

```
export function init(options) {
    //initialize module
}

export function doStuff(params) {
    //do stuff with options and other things
}
```

**1.2** *example.js*

```
var m = require('my-module');
m.init({thing: 'doodad'});
m.doStuff('bwoah');
```

I'm rewriting this in TS (targeting ES6), and plan to write the module as a class that can take a constructor (in lieu of `init()`), letting me write nice things like -

**1.3** *example-new.js*

```
import {Thing} from 'my-module';
const aThing1 = new Thing({thing: 'doodad'});
const aThing2 = new Thing();
aThing2.init({thing: 'doodad'});
aThing1.doStuff('bwoah');
aThing2.doStuff('bwoah');
// If I can do at least one of aThing1 or aThing2, I can die a happy man.
```

The rewritten TypeScript module looks like this -

**1.4** *my-module-new.js*

```
class Thing {
    options: Object;
    constructor(options: Object) {
        this.options = options;
    }
    init(options: Object) {
        this.options = options;
        return this;
    }
    doStuff(thingForStuff: string) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

*What I'd like to achieve*

I want to maintain full backwards-compatibility with the old API as well. So ideally, I should be able to do **both 1.2 and 1.3**.

*What I've tried so far*

1. `export`ing the `Thing` class; this lets me do 1.3, but not 1.2.
2. `export`ing a singleton, with `export default new Thing()`; this lets me do 1.3, but not 1.2.
3. Writing something like this -

   ```
   export class Thing {
       options: Object;
       constructor(options: Object) {
           this.options = options;
       }
       init(options: Object) {
           this.options = options;
           return this;
       }
       doStuff(thingForStuff: string) {
           // ...
       }
   }

   const singleThing = new Thing();

   export function init(options) {
      return singleThing.init(options);
   }

   export function doStuff(string) {
      return singleThing.doStuff(string);
   }
   ```

This works well with both 1.2 and 1.3 - but this seems tedious to basically duplicate each function.

Surely there must be a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we can! © In "Thing" file combine `default export` and `export`:

```
export class Thing {
    init() { }
}

export default new Thing();
```